# Models are missing in strongly typed view drop-down

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, view

First of all, I apologize if this question is unclear, I am going to try and be as clear as possible.

My solution has 2 projects: Models and View/Controller. The View/Controller project knows what is in the Models project but not vice-versa.

I have created some Text Templates to automatically create CRUD Pages that work when I use the Add View dialog box to add new Views. This obviously happens in the View/Controller project. I've been using this without issues for a long time.

I am able to run the project without syntax errors or runtime errors, but when I use the Add View Dialog Box to try and create a new page, I choose the strongly typed option and I do not see anything from the Models project.

Things I have tried:
Reattaching the DLL for the Models as a reference to the View/Controller project again.
Build and Rebuild as well as Cleans
Manually typing everything in the dialog box (fails).

I do not want to create this page manually, as it will make errors/bugs very likely whereas the Template will reduce the amount of bugs I am likely to encounter.

Comment: what asp.net mvc framework version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how it did it, but I cleaned the project again (after failed attempts) and it finally works.

Comment: Great! congrats and hope some thoughts of mine were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Before Adding View just Build the solution and then add view it will work. if it will not work then you can again concern with me i will give you another solution